# Spring TCP support High CPU utilisation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm using spring [TCP support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html) to create a TCP server.

I noticed that the CPU is running at 91% when I sent only one request. 
This is my code

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.IntegrationComponentScan;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractServerConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.MessageConvertingTcpMessageMapper;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.AbstractByteArraySerializer;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.ByteArrayMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter;

@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class TCPServerConfig {

  @Value("${tcp.listener.port}")
  private int port;

  @Bean
  public MessageConvertingTcpMessageMapper mapper(final MessageConverter messageConverter) {
    return new MessageConvertingTcpMessageMapper(messageConverter);
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
    return new ByteArrayMessageConverter();
  }


  @Bean
  public TcpInboundGateway tcpInGate(final AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final TcpInboundGateway inGate = new TcpInboundGateway();
    inGate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    inGate.setRequestChannel(fromTcp());

    return inGate;
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel fromTcp() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverCF(
      final AbstractByteArraySerializer byteArraySerializer) {
    final TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
        new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(this.port);
    connectionFactory.setDeserializer(byteArraySerializer);
    connectionFactory.setSerializer(byteArraySerializer);
    return connectionFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public AbstractByteArraySerializer byteArraySerializer() {
    return new ByteArrayCustomeSerializer();
  }
}
```

and this is the how I convert and log the messages

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.EMPTY;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank;


import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessageEndpoint;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Transformer;

@Slf4j
@MessageEndpoint
class TCPMessageProcessor {

  @Transformer(inputChannel = "fromTcp", outputChannel = "toProcess")
  public String convertInput(final byte[] bytes) {
    if(ArrayUtils.isEmpty(bytes)){
      return EMPTY;
    }

    String inboundMessage = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("ASCII"));
    log.info("Converted the message to string: '{}'. Handing it processor", inboundMessage);
    return inboundMessage;
  }

  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toProcess")
  public String process(final String message) {
    if(isBlank(message)){
      return EMPTY;
    }

      log.info("Started processing message '{}'", message);

      return "some response";
    }
}
```

I add logging and found that once the application receives the first request it serves it correctly then calls `ByteArrayCustomeSerializer#doDeserialize` multiple times every second with **input stream of empty byte array**. Can anyone please provide insight on why is this happening and how one might avoid this behavior?

This is from `org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection`

```
  "threadId":"pool-1-thread-3", "message":"Message received GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=*****, ip_connectionId=localhost:*****:*****:d313c398-fc80-48dd-b9c1-f447c9172f09, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=1fd69791-c300-787b-c5cc-281a360ae8f4, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1521623822108}]"
```

Comment: Despite repeating empty data calls 68% is still quite high usage.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a bug in your `ByteArrayCustomeSerializer` - edit the question to show the code.

Most likely you are not detecting the end of stream.

If the stream closes between messages, you need to throw a `SoftEndOfStreamException` to signal that the socket has closed in an "expected" fashion. If the stream closes during message deserialization, throw some other exception.

Comment: thanks for the reply. when I added the SoftEndOfStreamException, the doDeserialize method gets called twice first time with the payload I send, with is processed correctly then another call that results in SoftEndOfStreamException. Is there a way to get rid of that extra call?

Comment: No; we have to call it again to see if there is another message following the first one - what is your concern about the second call?

Comment: Problem with that would be that throwing SoftEndOfStreamException will end up being recorded as an error. making monitoring a bit messier. Although it might be easy to configure monitoring tools to ignore this error though. 
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: That is simply not true; it's not considered an error and is not logged; it's a signal to the calling code that the socket closed "normally", as expected and processing on this socket should stop. See [the code here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/TcpNetConnection.java#L236).

Comment: You're correct. found a snippet in our code that was catching Exception and  logging it as error.